# Stop an onClick function happening

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a bunch of elements with `class="pageOpener"` that progress through some pages.
They have jQuery `.on('click', ... )` events attached.
On a certain page I want to validate some input before moving on so it's got `id="continuebutton"` and its own click listener. I thought I'd be able to somehow cancel the class-wide event from within the id specific one if I wanted to but I've not been able to manage that yet. I think one of the problems is that the class event fires before the id (it's attached before).

Is there any way to make the id event fire first?
I'd like to keep my code in this order but if the only way to do it is to put the `id.on('click', ... )` before the `class.on('click', ... )` then I could do that.

Then what would be the correct way to stop the class event firing? return true?

Comment: Just to confirm, moving the `id.on('click', ... )` before makes it fire first. I'd preferable like to be able to set it as a higher priority and place it afterwards though. This doesn't appear possible though.

Comment: See my answer regarding custom events, really, this is a perfect situation to use those to not rely on code sequence/structure an still achieve your goals - sets the "priority" by managing the event firing sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation for `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Any other handlers attached on the current element will run however. To prevent that, call `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`. (Event handlers bound to an element are called in the same order that they were bound.)

You'll need to bind your id-based `click` event handler first (so it runs first), and call `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` inside of its function to stop the other, class-based `click` event handler from being executed.

Comment: IF you cannot rely on your code being structured/bound in sequence, or if someone else changes it later, this will break.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Are you the one who downvoted? They've said in the question that they **can** rely on the event handlers being bound in the correct order, and they're aware that the solution is highly dependent on the order in which the event handlers are being bound.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - since that is NOT the only way, we are both actually correct here :) - A. manage by reliance on code structure/sequence or B. manage the actual events with no reliance on code structure.  I see the question as `"Is there any way to make the id event fire first?"` actually.

Answer (score 1):

IF you cannot rely on your code being structured/bound in a certain way or if someone changes it later not knowing about this requirement, structure/sequence change will break it.  I resolved a similar issue using custom events.  These can be in any order and do not have a structure reliance.
  For example you could do:

```
$('.pageOpener').on('click', function(){
  // check the ID:
  if ($(this).prop('id') === 'continuebutton'){
     $('#continuebutton').trigger('myCustom');
  }
  else {
     $(this).trigger('myPageOpenerClick');
  }
});
$('.pageOpener').on('myPageOpenerClick', function(){
  // do that page opener stuff here
});

$('#continuebutton').on('myCustom', function(){
  // do that page custom stuff here
  alert('Howdy, handling id stuff');
  //trigger the other event now that stuff above is done:
  $(this).trigger('myPageOpenerClick');
});
```

Comment: I make the assumption here that your element `id="continuebutton"` also has the `class='pageOpener'` attribute.  IF that is not the case, you can simply put both those selectors in the click event handler.

Comment: I like this custom event stuff and I might use this in future. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use .off('click') to unbind the click listener.

[Official docs](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Update:

You can also do something like this.

```
$(".your_class").on("click", function(event){
  if($(this).attr("id")=="continuebutton"){
    return false;
  }else{
    //Continue handling the click event
  }

});
```

Comment: Then you can check for the id of the clicked element inside the click handler. Check the updated code.

Comment: I don't want to fully unbind the event, just stop it occurring this one time if certain conditions aren't met. Anthony's answer is what I was looking for, thanks for the help however :)

Comment: I agree with @AnthonyGrist on this one, unbinding AFTER the event has fired will not help resolve this situation as it would fire on both handlers.  Same for the return `false`.